# Custom Attribute Tab in Magento2 Easy Tabs

Tags: magento2

In Magento1 in the static block:

```
 {{block type="core/template"
 template="catalog/product/product_technology.phtml"}}
```

And then in the product_technology.phtml file:

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_prodID = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();  $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_prodID );

    $attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set');    $attributeSetModel->load($_product->getAttributeSetId());   $attributeSetName  = $attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName();

?>

<div class="box-collateral box-additional">


        <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table-4">
            <col width="25%" />
            <col />
            <tbody>             <?php if (0 == strcmp($attributeSetName, 'Clothing')): ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label">Clothing Shape</th>
                    <td class="data"><?php echo $_product->getClothing_shape() ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label">Outer Fabric</th>
                    <td class="data"><?php echo $_product->getOuter_fabric() ?></td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <th class="label">Clothing Lining</th>
                    <td class="data"><?php echo $_product->getClothing_lining() ?></td>
                </tr>               <?php elseif (0 == strcmp($attributeSetName, 'Sleeping Bags')): ?>      
                <tr>
                    <th class="label">Outer Fabric</th>
                    <td class="data"><?php echo $_product->getOuter_fabric() ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label">Inner Fabric</th>
                    <td class="data"><?php echo $_product->getInner_fabric() ?></td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <th class="label">Filling</th>
                    <td class="data"><?php echo $_product->getFilling() ?></td>
                </tr>               <?php endif; ?>     
            </tbody>
        </table>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table-4')</script>

</div>
```

In Magento2 in the static block:

```
 {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product_technology_file" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/product_technology.phtml.phtml"}}
```

And then in the product_technology.phtml file: ???

the Mage registry is deprecated in Magento2

Answer (score 1):

**Mage::registry** cannot be marked as **@deprecated in Magento2** as

Magento **2 does have a similar registry object that should help easily** got the transition for extensions. The class is **Magento\Framework\Registry**, and you can inject it in any constructor.

```
public function __construct(//... 
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    //...
)
{
    //...
    $this->registry     = $registry;
    //...
}
```

and then set variables with

```
$this->registry->register('test_var', 'this is a test!');
```

and fetch those variables back (even from a differnt object – Magento\Framework\Registry is a shared/singleton object)

```
echo $this->registry->registry('test_var');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output'); 

class Attributes {


 protected $_registry; 


 public function __construct(        
   \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_registry = $registry;
     }
   }

$_prodID  =$this->registry->registry('current_product')->getId();

     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_prodID);

    $attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set');
    $attributeSetModel->load($_product->getAttributeSetId());
    $attributeSetName  = $attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName();
```

I'm getting an undefined property error for $registry

```
Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined property: Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::$registry in /var/www/html/Magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php on line 110
```